# jQuery .before() then find it's content and apply the for loop. What am I doing wrong

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, for-loop

I need to dynamically add a couple of things like container then find it in DOM and fill with a list of numbers. Here is the way I do it but I feel like it is redundant and maybe I should do it another way. The only issue is that I have to do it all with javascript and cant hard code any container. That is why first I add it and then try to find it.

JS Bin working example http://jsbin.com/okikohu/1/

The code:

```
<script>
    $(function(){

      var obj = $('form'),
          total = 6;

        obj.before('<div class="container"/>');
        var container = $('body').find('.container');

        for (var i = 0, limit = total; i < limit; i++) {

                container.append('-<span class="step" id="is'+(i+1)+'">'+(i+1)+'</span>-');

      }

    });
  </script>

<form>some form</form>
```

Comment: What exactly do you think is redundant?

Comment: @Bergi I thought that maybe there is a callback for .before() so I could make sure that I find the container only after it is added. Or maybe it is possible to make a reference while adding container and avoid the .find() function passing through the whole BODY again

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ```
> obj.before('<div class="container"/>');
> var container = $('body').find('.container');
> ```

Instead of using [`before()`](http://api.jquery.com/before/) and then a DOM query, you could create the element with the [`jQuery(html)` constructor](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery2) and simply [`insertBefore()`](http://api.jquery.com/insertBefore/) it somewhere while still holding the reference:

```
var total = 6,
    container = $('<div class="container"/>').insertBefore('form');
```

Comment: This is beautiful! Exactly what I was expecting to improve. Looks good to me http://jsbin.com/okikohu/2/ and you?